# Object in a rotate loop in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was making a function so that my object can turn around. So I made this function:

```
void Drehen(){
    if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0.1){
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f));
        vorne = true;
    }

    if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > -0.1){
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f));
        vorne = false;
    }

    
}
```

The function checks the input if the player goes forwards or backwards and rotates him in the direction via `transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f));`

Now, every time I start the game I am able to go forward but as soon as I go backward it flips every side every frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's pretty obvious.

1. [`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) rotates the object from the current rotation about the given amount so

   ```
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
   ```

   does absolutely nothing at all and in

   ```
    transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
   ```

   you rotate it by 180° every frame.
2. In the second condition you have `> -0.1` which is the case all the time while you don't press the negative key.

   It should probably rather be `< 0.1f`.

What you want is probably rather e.g.

```
var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

if(horizontal > 0.1f)
{
    // or localRotation depending on your needs
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    vorne = true;
}
else if(horizontal < 0.1f)
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180f, 0f);
    vorne = false;
}
```

Or actually as alternative you could also do

```
var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

if(Mathf.Abs(horizontal) > 0.1f)
{
    transform.forward = new Vector3(0, 0, horizontal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f);
```

Comment: Did not fix it unfortunatly but thx

Comment: @TimothyKardel I made an edit, maybe it works now

Comment: I have already tested all of the possible rotating methods but no one worked out. I think there must be a problem with detekting if the player is moving right or left because if i check the scene i can see that every 2nd frame he is in fact in the right rotation but every next frame he is facing right again so it must perform both if statements so every time it runs through when i push A for walking left my Charackter goes left and right at the same time

Comment: Yes it looks like you are detecting the input every frame, and applying the rotation every frame. The rotation will be relative, which is why it switches 180 degrees every frame. Either you can apply the relative rotation once only, or use the method I posted which applies a fixed rotation

Comment: The methode moves the whole camera (which is atteched to the player as a child). Can i deactivate this in any way? I already made the Camera static

Comment: Yeah I would have a child (for position) and your camera is a child of that like it is now. But make your character a child also and only apply the rotation there.